# Read file in as 32 bit binary data c++

Tags: c++, io

I need to read a file in as binary data, making sure the file is an even number of 32 bit words (I can add padding bytes of 0s if I need).

I've fiddled around with ios::binary but is there something I'm missing? For instance:

```
string name1 = "first", name2 = "sec", name3 = "third";
int j = 0, k = 0;
ifstream ifs(name1.c_str());
ifs >> j; 
ifs.close();
```

Is this something I need to utilize? I'm fairly new to the language.

Comment: `>>` is formatted I/O. You want `read()` (and open the file in binary mode!).

Comment: For this kind of thing, I would honestly just use C-style `fread`...it is much less clunky...

Comment: The thing you were missing is the actual meaning of the `ios::bin` flag. Don't assume but study the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::ifstream ifs(name1.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary);
if (!ifs)
{
    // error opening file
}
else
{
    int32_t j;
    do
    {
        j = 0;
        ifs.read(&j, sizeof(j));
        if (ifs)
        {
            // read OK, use j as needed
        }
        else
        {
            if (ifs.eof())
            {
                // EOF reached, use j padded as needed
            }
            else
            {
                // error reading from file
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    while (true);

    ifs.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to read 32bits using a similar method as Remy Lebeau. This code is compatible with C++03.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fstream>

// Rest of code...

std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary | std::ifstream::beg);

int32_t word;
if(!file){
    //error
} else {
    while(file.is_open()){
        if(file.eof()){ printf("END\n"); break; }

        word = 0;
        file.read((char*)&word,sizeof(word));

        //Do something
        printf("%d\n",word);
    }
}
```

Note that I do not add padding if the file is not in exact increments of 32. I'll update the code if I add that functionality.